# Run code after the animation is finished

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm

I am using MVVM Light. I have created a window that looks like this:

```
<Window Name="MainWindow" ...>
  <Window.Resources>
    ...
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="mainVM" />
    ...
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visConv" />
    ...
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource mainVM}>
    ...
    <Button Command="{Binding RaiseMyControl}" />
    ...
    <my:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding MyControlVisible, 
        Converter={StaticResource visConv}}" />
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

So basically, the `MainViewModel` is a view model class for the window. It contains:

- `bool MyControlVisible` property which is binded to `MyUserControl`'s `Visibility` 
  property
- `RelayCommand RaiseMyControl` command which purpose is to set the value of the 
  `MyControlVisible` property to `true` (default is false).

Clicking the button in the window results in the appearance of the `MyUserControl` - simple.

`MyUserControl` user control looks like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <viewModels:MyUserControlViewModel x:Key="userControlVM" />
    ...
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource userControlVM}>
    ...
    <Border Width="200" Height="100" Background="Red">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyUserControlText}" />
    </Border>
    <!-- This border has a DataTrigger bound to "bool Fading" property of 
         the view model. When Fading is true, the border fades in through 
         an animation. When it is false, the border fades out. -->
    ...
    <Button Command="{Binding CloseMyControl}" />
  </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Again, very simple. The `MyUserControlViewModel` is a view model class for the user control. It contains:

- `string MyUserControlText` property which is binded to `TextBlock`'s `Text` 
  property
- `bool Fading` property which is binded to border's data template, and is used to make 
  the border fade in or out
- `RelayCommand CloseMyControl` command which does two things: 1. It sets the `Fading` 
  property to `false` to make the border fade out, and 2. it sets the `Visibility` 
  property of the user control to `Collapsed`.

Here's the problem: as soon as the `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed`, the user control disappears. I need it to fade out first and then to disappear afterwards. How can I make it happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the visibility belongs to the fade-out i would run two animations at the same time. Additionally to your fade-animation (of whatever type or composite that may be) you can create a `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` which sets the Visibiliy at the key time at which the fade ends.

XAML example:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Additionally all storyboards and animations have a `Completed` event to which you could subscribe and just set the value right away.

---

To direct the animation at another control use `Storyboard.Target` for complex references, or `Storyboard.TargetName` for reference by name.

To animate the UserControl you could try:

```
Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

or

```
Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=my:MyUserControl}}"
```

Both should work if the logical tree is intact.

Comment: @H.B. Hello again! :) Since the animation is set on the border and I need the `Visibility` to target my user control, how can I reference that from this animation?

Comment: Added some more info on that to the answer, see if it works out.

Comment: I added the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, but it won't collapse the `Visibility` property. It remains `Visible`. I know this because I've temporarily set the background color of the root layout grid to yellow. So, the border fades out, but the control remains visible, i.e. yellow. Any thoughts?

Comment: Right, the `AncestorType` should just be `UserControl`, since the type is only applied outside, tried it with a UserControl of my own.

Comment: After changing the `AncestorType` it still doesn't work on my side. Is my binding of the `Visibility` property in the main window messing things up maybe?

Comment: That could be possible, but you should just try what happens if you remove it instead of asking me -.-

Comment: Output window reports an error: "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames' (HashCode=594534); target property is 'Target' (type 'DependencyObject')"

Comment: That is odd, sorry, i do not know what goes wrong there, it works for me (even with a binding on the instance's visibility), probably something in your context is interfering....

Comment: I just tested my initial binding by the way, defining the derived type as `AncestorType` works just as well.

Comment: In the end I used `Completed` event on storyboard to make it work. I don't like the idea of having an event handler in code-behind, as I strive to fulfill the MVVM recommendations, but in this case, I am willing to let it slide as it is related to view only.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting the visibility to Collapsed as part of the fade out animation, not a separate line in the CloseMyControl command.